# <button> always redirecting after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button

My button:

```
<button onclick="return DeleteImg(this,event);">Delete</button>
```

My code:

```
function DeleteImg(Obj,e) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the file?')) return false;
    var n = new PostData('/Pictures/Delete/', 'Type=Home&Name=' + window.LargeImage.src.split('/')[5]);
    n.onResponse = function (t) {
        var n = JSON.parse(t);
        if (n.Success) ShowMsg('Image Deleted, it will be gone when you refresh.');
        else ShowMsg(n.Msg);
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Post data function:

```
function PostData(e, t) {
    var n = false;
    this.onResponse = function (e) {};
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) n = new XMLHttpRequest;
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) n = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    else {
        this.onResponse(JSON.stringify({
            Success: false,
            Msg: 'Your browser does not support AJAX, please upgrade to Google Chrome, Mozzila Firefox or Internet Explorer 10',
            ElementId: undefined
        }))
    }
    n.open('POST', e, true);
    n.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var r = this;
    n.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (n.readyState == 4 && n.status == 200) r.onResponse(n.responseText)
    };
    n.send(t)
}
```

Whenever the button is clicked and the user clicks okay to the confirmation box, the page redirects to another page (No idea what, my FCP just redirects it to page not found though so it doesn't exist) and the code isn't ran.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm suspecting something is wrong with PostData. Can you post the function here?

Comment: Added that now, though I have used it many times before and it has worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default a button is a `submit` button which causes your page to redirect. You can fix by setting the button type.

```
<button type="button" onclick="return DeleteImg(this,event);">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Wasn't `e.preventDefault; return false` supposed to cancel this behavior?

Comment: Added this, still redirects.

Comment: Very likely an issue in one of your other function calls. Either `PostData` or `ShowMsg`

Comment: ShowMsg just sets the text of a div, PostData just makes an AJAX request and returns the result. Also I have used both the functions on another page, the only difference being the DeleteImg function was adjusted to hide the image and it works fine there.

Comment: Other possibility then is that you overlapping forms in your html. Regardless, I'm certain the problem exists in code you're not showing here if setting the type doesn't work.

Comment: It must be a problem with my code, I just can't see where. The parent of the button is a div, the parent of the div is another div and the parent of that is body.

Comment: Does the page still redirect if you click cancel?

Comment: Yeah it redirects whatever I click.

Comment: I am a complete idiot, the parent div has a redirect onclick on it. Sorry for wasting your time, thanks for coming to help.